Как убрать это с моей страницы WPF?

Как убрать эту белую панельку с моей страницы WPF?

<Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" ... >

есть несколько вариантов ,если вы используете Frame то добавьте NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" в свойства фрейма,  если она появляется в Page то используйте этот пример:
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="HomePage"
    ShowsNavigationUI="False"
    >

или
public partial class HomePage : Page
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Hide host's navigation UI
            this.ShowsNavigationUI = false;
        }
    }

но мб произойти ещё какая-то непредвиденная проблема ,чтобы наверняка используйте
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(ApplicationPriority.Render, new Action(() =>
{
  var navWindow = Window.GetWindow(this) as NavigationWindow;
  if(navWindow!=null) navWindow.ShowsNavigationUI = false;
}));

